# What difference it makes to normalize the features

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, cross-validation, scikit-learn

I came across this problem today, I was training a basic logistic regression on the Iris dataset using one vs all approach, It's my own implementation of logistic regression which uses gradient descent and I found out my model accuracy was 66% as a class  Iris-versicolor is not linearly separable. Here is the screenshot (one vs all, one class is positive and all others are negative) [image]

(notice these features are not normalized)

log-loss was some like -:
3.39, 8.42, 0.86 ,1.07, 8.52 on some iterations.

After applying mean normalization to feature like :
[image]

(notice these features are mean normalized now)

log loss went down to 0.63
0.47, 0.46, 0.45, 0.45.
And I got an accuracy of 96% - 100% (on hyperparameter optimization)

Please if someone could shed a light on me so I could understand what's going on in here, what affect normalized features is having on my classifier than unnormalized features. These two classes are still not linearly separable, right?  I want to understand it as bad as I want to see aliens in area 51. Thanks

Edit: Here is the link to google colab notebook to make things more clearer
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16AaPWCPeV-9i4aZV3XddDaBh7VlUCQmO

Comment: I fear things I cannot explain. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Hi, Here is the link of ipynb on google colab, feel free to comment. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ER0VKGfyodJoOstr-tZuEIxJESCHBM-o
This should make things clearer. Note * if you apply  mean normalization (set normal_flag = 1), then log loss on validation set for class 2 goes down drastically and hence improves accuracy.

Comment: Hi, apart from "Not a programming question" could you help me with my question? I really need to know what's going on, it feels like mean normalization is making data linearly separable.

Comment: a) you should mention its your own implementation not scikit learns ( and using gradient descent).  b) normalisation normally means subtracting mean and dividing by standard deviation - whereas here you are just subtracting mean. c) I can;t explain the difference.  I would check what results you get from scikit learn.  either its a bug in your code, or your learning rate is too high and ?perhaps the mean normalisation is affected by this??

Answer (score 1):

I believe it may be a case of gradient descent not being able to converge.

When we are doing ML with a Logistic Regression we are essentially defining a cost function, trying "something", checking what direction the gradient that reduces the cost function is pointing, and following that direction in our next attempt.

Ideally you want something like the image on the right:

[image]

However if your features are on very different scales, you will have a problem like the one on the left for Gradient Descent to solve. It will take a step, overshoot, take a step, overshoot, etc. You can technically find the minimum, but it's a much harder problem.

So in summary, when you normalise your features, you are helping gradient descent find the optimum. And gradient descent is your friend.

*[Le sauce of the image](https://csesmu.blogspot.com/2015/10/feature-scaling.html)*